# Using regex to extract multiple strings

Tags: regex, xml, string, replace

I've looked at quite a few different posts relating to this but I'm still running into a few problems.

I need to remove the value between multiple specific tags, without touching others with a similar name.  For example, remove value for "LastName" but not for "Last".

Here is my sample test string

```
<jv:FirstName>TEST</jv:FirstName>
<jv:MiddleInitial>TEST</jv:MiddleInitial>
<jv:LastName>TEST</jv:LastName>
<jv:EmployerName>TEST</jv:EmployerName>
<jv:LocationName>TEST</jv:LocationName>
<jv:CallerName>TEST</jv:CallerName>
<jv:Last>TEST</jv:Last>
```

I only want to remove the values for FirstName, LastName, and MiddleInitial.

This is what I currently have for my regex pattern:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"<(jv:[FirstName|MiddleInitial|LastName].*>).*?</\1, "<$1</$1");
```

This pattern works but it is also pulling the "LocationName" and "Last" tags.

Is there any way to only pull specifc strings?

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser instead of a regex? Your sanity will thank you.

Comment: `[FirstName|MiddleInitial|LastName]` looks incorrect, the `[]` is a character set, it's not using those words. Then you follow it with `.*` which matches anything. So it's matching Last because you can spell it with those characters, and LocationName because it hits L.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parentheses instead of braces.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"<(jv:(?:FirstName|MiddleInitial|LastName)>).*?</\1, "<$1</$1");
```

Braces signify matching any character within them one time. Parentheses match the full string.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head for hours

Comment: Sorry about that, I will make sure to do that for all my future questions. thank you for informing me. And thanks again for all your help!